# Local Notification with different body text every day

Tags: swift, notifications, local

my aim is to build a local notification which should be triggered every day. The notification body should be a different one every day.
This is the String Array of which one string should be shown in the notifiaction.
It doesn´t matter if the String gets choosen randomly or in the sequence the array is ordered.

```
var arrayText: [String] = ["text1",  
                           "text2",  
                           "text3",  
                           "text4",  
                           "text5"]
```

This is how far I got. Just a normal local notification with everytime the same body text.

```
func scheduleNotifications()
    {

              let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

              center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                  if !granted {
                      print("Something went wrong")
                  }
              }

              let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
              content.title = "Test"
              content.body = "test"
              content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

              let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
              let now = Date()
              var components = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: now)

              components.hour = 18
              components.minute = 42
              components.second = 10

              let date = gregorian.date(from: components)!   

              let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date)    

              let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)

              let uuidString = UUID().uuidString
              let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: uuidString, content: content, trigger: trigger)

              center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
                  if let error = error {
                      // Something went wrong
                  }
              })
    }

}
```

Help would be awesome. And thank you for every helpfull answer
Yours sincerely
Tell aka. Relbot

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but currently, the way to do this is to create multiple notification requests (also, do not set the trigger's repeats to true). Then set new ones when the user opens the app. What David Chopin suggests, should work (in theory) but doesn't.

```
let array = ["text1", "text2", "text3", "text4", "text5"]
let chosenDate = Date()
for item in 0...64 {
   let date = chosenDate.adding(Calendar.Component.day, value: item)
   let triggerDaily = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .hour, .minute], from: date)
   let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: false)
   let text = self.getRandom() {
   let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
   content.body = array[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))] 
   content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

   let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: quote.id!, content: content, trigger: trigger)
   UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `content.body = "test"` to `content.body = arrayText[Int(arc4random_uniform(5))]`. This will make it so that the `content.body` is equal to a random element within `arrayText`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know where I need to write this so that it (the whole notification code) gets triggered also if the user didn´t opened the app.